# Background Image Jitters on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, background-image, css-position, fixed

I have a fixed background image which shakes when scrolling on Chrome, no issue on other browsers. Style:

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: column nowrap;
align-items: center;
background: url(../url/toActualIMG.jpg) fixed no-repeat center center/cover;
```

Comment: Could you add more example code, specifically how the HTML is structured and what selector this example CSS is tied to?

Comment: Try adding `height:100%`. It will be easier if we have the HTML structure and CSS.